# Dynamically cast response to generic class

Tags: java, generics, dynamic

I have the following generic class:

```
public class ErrorJsonResponse<T> {

    private String error;
    private String errCode;
    private String message;
    private T data;

    public ErrorJsonResponse() {
    }

    public ErrorJsonResponse(String error, T data) {
        setError(error);
        setData(data);
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I need to cast to this class dynamically during run time, like:

```
(ErrorJsonResponse <runtimeType>) result
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't. Where should the runtimeType come from?

Comment: Generics don't(*) exist at runtime, they are a compiler trick to help you use the right type & reduce casting & compiler warnings. Before that you had to use the `List` class like `String string = (String) list.get(123)` because all the compiler could guarantee is that it contains `Object`s. It still contains just `Object`s today due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) but it looks much nicer and got much safer when using the code. Anyways: can you show an example of where you need to cast like that? Just casting to `<?>` or so usually works

Comment: Hanno, I will determine the type during process.

Comment: this is code snippet where I want to use generic type:

for (HttpMessageConverter messageConverter : messageConverters) {
            if (messageConverter.canRead(ErrorJsonResponse.class, contentType)) {
                return (ErrorJsonResponse) messageConverter.read(ErrorJsonResponse.class, response);
            }
        }
I need to cast response dynamically with runtimeType.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast generic generic classes like this:

```
public void onResult(ErrorJsonResponse<?> response) {
    ErrorJsonResponse<RuntimeException> castedResponse = (ErrorJsonResponse<RuntimeException>) response;
}
```

You **cannot** cast them like this:

```
public void onResult(ErrorJsonResponse<OtherException> response) {
    ErrorJsonResponse<RuntimeException> castedResponse = (ErrorJsonResponse<RuntimeException>) response;
}
```

In the above example `ErrorJsonResponse<OtherException>` and `ErrorJsonResponse<RuntimeException>` are inconvertible types

Comment: you can cheat and cast to something intermediate: `ErrorJsonResponse<RuntimeException> castedResponse = (ErrorJsonResponse<RuntimeException>)(Object) response;`